# Can confusing wording in Chrome flags be explained?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-flags

in [this](http://chrome://flags/#disable-eol-notification) chrome flag, the wording is very confusing to me.

[image]

```
    Disable Device End of Life notification. Chrome OS
    Disable Notifcation when Device is End of Life. #disable-eol-notification
    Disable
```

this is weird because the disable option (the third line) and the wording of the flag make a double negative. My aim is to see the eol notification but I cant decide whether this flag disables disabling (enables) or just disables.

Please help, this has been puzzling me for a while and my eol date is rapidly approaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight forward; It allows you to disable the notification by clicking on Disable.
If you do want to get the notification then don't Disable it - don't click on the disable link/button.
I hope it's clear enough.